# How to get the image of the reports & dashboard in salesforce using API?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

I have the requirement to get the image of the dashboard to reproduce it in the another app connected to Salesforce. How can I able to get the image? Is there any API for that?

I have searched in the workbench for the similar API to meet my requirement. But I can't able to find anything that meets my requirement.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you need to interact with Salesforce reporting is the [Reports and Dashboards REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_intro.htm).

This API does not provide functionality to produce an image file. However, you can get the [dashboard results](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_dashboard_get_results.htm), which your application can then interpret and render. Note that the "fact map" data structure returned by Salesforce is fairly complex.